# JS: mouse coordinates relative to an element

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Is it cross-browser to catch the mouse coordinates relative to a div box with this:

```
pos_x = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX-document.getElementById("thebox").offsetLeft;
pos_y = event.offsetY?(event.offsetY):event.pageY-document.getElementById("thebox").offsetTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me; change to your framework:

```
function assignPosition(element,event) {
cX=event.clientX; cY=event.clientY;
if ($$(element).pageYOffset)
   {
   rX=$$(element).pageXOffset;
   rY=$$(element).pageYOffset;
   }
if (document.body)
   {
   rX=document.body.scrollLeft;
   rY=document.body.scrollTop;
   }
if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
   {
   rX=document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
   rY=document.documentElement.scrollTop;
   }
cX+=rX;
cY+=rY;
$$(element).style.left=cX+"px";
$$(element).style.top=cY+"px";
}
```

Comment: @dusoft: Good stuff +1. Btw, which browser have you tested with it?

Comment: tested in Firefox, I Explorer 6, 7

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not have all/most of the browser types/versions to test on, you might take a look at this:
[W3C DOM Compatibility - Events](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_events.html#mousepos)
Linked from above: [W3C DOM Compatibility - CSS Object Model View](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html)

Gives you an idea of how compatible the codes are.

Answer (score 0):

```
function dodoubleclick(e){
             var mouseX, mouseY;

                if(e.offsetX) {
                    mouseX = e.offsetX;
                    mouseY = e.offsetY;
                }
                else if(e.layerX) {
                    mouseX = e.layerX;
                    mouseY = e.layerY;
                }
alert("mousex:"+mouseX+"and"+"mousey:"+mouseY);
```

}

this snippet will gives you mouse coordinates