# relative mouse coordinates in a DIV - javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm moving the mouse over a div  and I want to know the mouse coordinates with respect to the div origin. (upper left corner)

I expected the mousemove event to contain the relative (client?) coordinates of the mouse, but apparently it doesn't.

In firefox for instance, none of the event properties* contain relative coordinates

Am I missing something?

*clientX,Y - pageX,Y - screenX, y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not missing anything, but you'll need to calculate the relative coordinates yourself.

Something along these lines should do it (substitute jquery with w/e code you want to use to get the position):

```
var pos = $('div').position();
var relX = event.pageX - pos.left;
var relY = event.pageY - pos.top;
```

Also see: [JS: mouse coordinates relative to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815103/js-mouse-coordinates-relative-to-an-element) which covers some of the details on supporting other browsers (though if you're using jquery that may not be needed).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. I'm still curious though. Am I right in assuming that 'client' coordinates should be, well, relative to the element that's generating the event?

Comment: @johnsmith https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/MouseEvent and especially http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-MouseEvent-clientX

Comment: Phrogz, thanks. Well, seems that the standard doesn't do what I'd like it to do =P

Comment: http://jrharshath.wordpress.com/2008/09/20/javascript-mousemove-event-brouhaha-resolved/

"screenX/Y pair: they are available consistently across all browsers, and all do the same thing – get the coordinates with respect to the top left corner of you screen. But then, this value doesn’t really have much use, does it?"